# My app suffers when it has low speed connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My current application is using internet in order to download Google Maps (running iOS6). In addition, is connected to a server in order to retrieve info from a database, for user's details etc. My problem is that when iPhone is using mobile internet and the signal is too weak (no 3G) the map view is loaded having Apple maps on it. Need to wait 5-6 minutes in order to download Google maps and put them on the top of that as an overlay. There is any efficient way or trick in order to fix this situation. Does not looks good to the user to wait so much in order to display the maps(Google).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using any caching?  Is there a reason why you are not using Apple's maps?

Comment: Hello @propstm no, I am not using any caching. Yes, the reason why I am not using Apple's maps is because my app is restricted to campus area and it's buildings. Unfortunately, Apple's maps lack on this location (no buildings, no roads). Thanks for fast reply.